# Change the tabs in a Embedded TabBarController

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller which has two buttons and an embedded TabBarController.
I want to use the two button instead of the tab bar item. And for some reason cannot make it work.

MainView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var currentTab = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    
    @IBAction func item1Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentTab = 0
    }
    
    @IBAction func item2Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentTab = 1
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toControllers"{
            if let vc = segue.destination as? TabsViewController {
                vc.selectedIndex = currentTab

            }
        }
    }
}
```

TabBarController

```
import UIKit

class TabsViewController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I have two items in the storyboard,  so item 0 and 1 should be ok.

Maybe it is very simple, cannot figure it out myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Off the top of my head, a few thoughts. (1) Have you put in a breakpoint to make sure `vc.selectedTab = currentTab` is getting hit? (2) Have you tried "thinning out" your code. I'm seeing references to a navigation controller, a segue, IBOutlets, IBActions. Seems like there's many points of possible failure in your code. (3) Have you tried `didSet` instead of `willSet`? Do you know if that's where the issue is?

Comment: It is getting hit, but not updated after the first initialisation.

Comment: I updated a bit the code, got rid of the variable in the TabController, it was just getting triggered at the first initialisation, so it was not doing much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, here is the solution:

Changed the main controller to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var currentTab = 1
    private var tabViewController: UITabBarController?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    
    @IBAction func item1Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("click item1")
        tabViewController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }
    
    @IBAction func item2Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("click item2")
        tabViewController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toControllers"{
            if let vc = segue.destination as? TabsViewController {
                tabViewController = vc
            }
        }
    }
```